# Java Applications failed to display the result in console windows

Tags: java, mysql

I am learning java . I am trying to read the data and displaying the records in console windows  from mysql database . But the problem is when I run the code its build successfully but do not display the records .

Here is my connections class

```
package halifaxapp;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;
/**
/**
 *
 * @author Khundokar Nirjor
 */
public class MySQLJDBCUtil {
  public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;

        try (FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("db.properties")) {

            // load the properties file
            Properties pros = new Properties();
            pros.load(f);

            // assign db parameters
            String url = pros.getProperty("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8081/mysqljdbc");
            String user = pros.getProperty("root");
            String password = pros.getProperty("9090");

            // create a connection to the database
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }

}
```

Here is main methods .

```
package halifaxapp;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
/**
 *
 * @author Khundokar Nirjor
 */
public class HalifaxApp {


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        // 
        String sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email " +
                     "FROM candidates";

        try (Connection conn = MySQLJDBCUtil.getConnection();
             Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs    = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {

            // loop through the result set
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("first_name") + "\t" + 
                                   rs.getString("last_name")  + "\t" +
                                   rs.getString("email"));

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the screen shot when I run the applications .
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties file will be a name/value pair like

```
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8081/mysqljdbc
user=root
```

then you can use like

```
String url = pros.getProperty("url");
```

Also, when you catch an Exception, do

```
ex.printStackTrace();
```

rather than

```
System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
```

Comment: db.properties what doe it actually means in file steam methods . What are the properties by mean db.properties???

Comment: `db.properties` is a file name that contains the properties - have a read of https://www.baeldung.com/java-properties

Comment: What should I write instead of db.properties? As you can see username , password and URL is already defined..

Comment: The idea is that you can use a text file to store these values.  That means that if your url changes, then you can simply change the text file and viola, it will work.  If the values are hard-coded into your code, you would need to re-compile and re-deploy your code.  But, you can do that if you want.

Comment: Thank but I want display the records from MySQL database not from any hard coded text file. What will the correct approach for that??

Comment: **NO**, the properties file are containing the connection details e.g. url, user, password **NOT** the actual data - that still comes from the database

Comment: But as you can see all the credentials are defined like URL ,username and password in next line but why the records are not displaying in console window ??

Comment: Possible reasons are: a) there are no records b) there is an Exception.  Also in your console window it says `Cancelled by user` - what does this mean?

Comment: Records are exist I checked that but I am not sure about this cancelled by the use why it’s displaying this message . You mean the code is correct ??

Comment: No your original code was wrong and that it why I made an answer.  Also, it says `Build Failed` - you got to fix that

Comment: it saying this erros when i run it

Comment: db.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at halifaxapp.HalifaxApp.main(HalifaxApp.java:29)
Java Result: 1

Comment: so fix it.  Try learning to search for solutions to your problems.

Comment: Can you please tell me ??

Comment: create a file called `db.properties` - why do you just copy code that you do not understand?  One of your first lines is `new FileInputStream("db.properties")` - what do you think this is doing? What does your think that `FileInputStream` does? Hint: `FILE` has some meaning

Comment: As far I understood I have to create text file inside my project and defined properties like this url= =jdbc:mysql://localhost:.....,

Comment: Then user= root,

Comment: Then password =password

Comment: That is what the first few lines of my answer says.